# bash: Find the index of the first occurrence of a specific word in a string

Tags: bash

Given a sentence with words delimited by spaces,
how would i find the place of the first occurrence of a word?

e.g. the index of 'flower' in

```sh
sentence="That's a lovely flower you've got over there! Can i have a smell?"
```

should be 4

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: `there`, `can` and `smell` would return 0?

Comment: The index of "flower" in the string is 16 not 4. Maybe you meant as a expanded set of words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk` and setting record separator as field separator

```
awk -v p='flower' 'BEGIN {RS=FS} $0 ~ p {print NR}' <<<"$sentence"
4
```

If you are not planning to use regexps, like for example

```
awk -v p='[Ff]lower' ...
```

or

```
awk -v p='smell[:punct:]*' ...
```

to allow punctuation chars, then you can just check for equality as @karakfa suggested

```
awk -v p='flower' 'BEGIN {RS=FS} $0==p {print NR}'
```

also, if you want just the first occurence, add an `exit`

```
... {print NR; exit}'
```

Comment: perhaps check for equality instead of regex match.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' <<<"$sentence" | sed -n "/flower/="
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion to remove the rest of the string to get the first word, compare it to the search term, and use parameter expansion to remove the first word from the string.

```
#! /bin/bash
search=flower
sentence="That's a lovely flower you've got over there! Can i have a smell?"

i=1
while [[ $sentence = *' '* ]] ; do
    if [[ $search = ${sentence%% *} ]] ; then  # Remove from the first space.
        echo $i
        break
    fi
    sentence=${sentence#* }                    # Remove the first word.
    (( ++i ))
done
```

Or, you can populate an array with the words and iterate over the array:

```sh
read -ra words <<< "$sentence"
for i in "${!words[@]}" ; do
    if [[ ${words[i]} = $search ]] ; then
        echo $(( i+1 ))
        break
    fi
done
```

Or, you can select the part *before* the word, count the spaces in it (by removing everything that's not a space and checking the length of the remaining string) and add 2.

```sh
before=${sentence% $search *}
if [[ $before = $sentence ]] ; then
    echo Not found >&2
else
    spaces=${before//[^ ]}
    echo $(( 2 + ${#spaces} ))
fi
```

Or...

Comment: `read -ra words <<< "$sentence"` is safer, as it avoids pathname expansion. You can also iterate over the indices with `for i in "${!words[@]}"; do`

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0):

using multiple tools...

```
$ echo "$sentence" | tr ' ' \\n | grep -nxF flower | cut -d: -f1
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using combination of grep with head and awk

```
 grep 'flower' sampl.txt|head -1| awk '{split($0,data," ");for (word in data) {if (data[word]~/flower/){print word; break;}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`

```
sed '/\bflower\b.*/!d;s///;s/[^ ]//g' <<< "$sentence" | wc -c
```

This assumes there is exactly one space between two words and no leading spaces in the `$sentence`.